# Can I force Firefox to access the web using ssh and telnet?

Tags: linux, networking, firefox, ssh, browser

My problem is that there is a website that I can access only from a certain private network N. It is not some textual data, but a webapp, so no lynx.

I can access Firefox in a server in N using "ssh -X", but it is painstakingly slow. So slow that it takes approximately one minute for it to process a click...

It seems that the server has no support for "ssh -L" and I have no access to it so I didn't manage to create a tunnel. But I can use "telnet" when I connect to the server via a regular shell, so I can download the webpages.

So I figured out that if I could make Firefox in my machine access each resource via a ssh shell and a telnet request I would be set. Is that possible?

Comment: You said you tried "ssh -L" with no luck, but did you try "ssh -D <port>"?? This option creates a SOCKS proxy. And you can configure Firefox to use this proxy and navigate as if you where into the "N private network".

Comment: No, it is always "open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed"

Comment: It seems like a permissions problem. Are you using ports under 1024? If you do, try bigger numbers. Also, I know this is not a clever solution, but can you ssh to root account? It may help.

Comment: If ssh doesn't work, you can try opening two netcat instances. I think it will be better and easier solution than telnet: one netcat listening for an incoming request, and redirecting traffic to the second netcat. The second netcat connects to desired page.